detecting a wire cut in the car
I have been assigned the task of detecting a wire cut in the car.
It's part of my official project. I am a computer science engineer so my knowledge of electronic is bit limited so please bear with my naiveness.
The aim is to detect that the wire has been cut and then send a signal to the microcontroller where I do further processing. Initially for prototype, I am thinking of targettng just the headlight or backlight wires.
I have been googling around and found that Octocopulers or Hall based sensors can be used to detect current and send a signal. But I am not sure if this is the correct approach or what circuit to use.
Considering me as the beginner please can you suggest some simple approach .
Thanks
Alan

For what purpose it needs to detect a wire being cut by someone? Or just that the lamp is burnt out? Do you need to detect where the cut is, i.e. how many inches away from measuring point? Is the sensor at the side that powers the lamp, or at the side of the lamp? Is it a fixed device or does it need to be placed in place of lamp to detect where a cut is? Also which side of the lamp wire, positive or negative?

Purpose to buzz an alarm if wire cut is detected.  Using the lamp wire is just to for POC . No, no need to detect from where it is cut. I am thinking of putting a seson at the side that powers the lamp. Fixed device. Postivie side of the lamp wire.  Please let me know if anything else can help to clarify the scenario.

I think the accepted practice is to use transmission line theory and bounce signals down wires and look at the reflection. Sort of like tapping at the end of a pipe and deducing how long it is by the sound. But this is technically difficult. For you, say there's an incandescent bulb to ground at the far end, and you add a small series resistor. Measure the voltage between the resistor and bulb. If the same as the supply, then the wire is probably cut/bulb burned out. If this is the answer you want, "@" me here and I'll add some details and post it.

hmm. sorry, not sure. It looks to be a manual effort, I am looking for some automation here may be like if the wire cut is detected, then we can set a GPIO etc..
Please can you suggest what sensor can I use to detect the current or the voltage ?

COTS current sensors are usually just coils of wire and need additional circuitry and conditioning if expected to interface w/General Purpose Input Output pins.  Which may be 0V to 5V swing or 0V to 3V swing (you didn't specify).  You could do something tricky like connect it to a edge triggered interrupt pin. But you might also need to electrically clamp the voltage to protect the processor.  As you are operating in a electrically noisy environment.

Most cars can detect such open load errors. Why reinvent the wheel?

Consider a method used where signals are bounced down a wire and the reflection is analyzed. Not only can such a method detect a break in the wire but can also localize it. This is referred to as Time Domain Reflectometry (TDR).
This is rather a technical approach and costly to implement continuously on many wire cables.
Alternatively consider a simpler approach. The constraints of the problem were not described. Let us assume a 12 Volt supply and a 20mA incandescent light bulb.
We can add a small series resistor to this circuit. Large enough to measure a voltage drop but small enough not to noticeably diminish the brightness of the bulb.  The resistance of the bulb is:
V = I * R
12 = 0.02 * R
R = 600 ohms

We assume a 10% drop in voltage will not noticeably dim the bulb so pick a series resistor of about 60 ohms. (Resistors values a pick to be of logarithmic relationship to one another. So sourcing a 60 ohm resistor may be difficult.  Fortunately sourcing a close value should work if that value is substituted in the calculations.)
Design a circuit where 12V power is passed through the 60 ohm resistor which is in turn connected to the cable powering the 20mA incandescent bulb. Connect the ADC of the embedded processor to the point in the circuit between the 60 ohm resistor and the bulb. Warning, the ADC input of most embedded processors can only handle voltages between its power rails.  Use a resistor network to voltage divide the signal to ensure the processor is not exposed to excessive voltages.  Alternatively, source a COTS voltage meter capable of communicating to a processor (i.e. has a SPI, I2C or other type of communication port).
In your software, you will need to determine which state the circuit under test is in.  Un-powered (sensing no voltage), powered and open (broken cable or burned out bulb) (sensing 12 volts) or powered and normal (sensing 12 - (12 * 10%) or 10.9 Volts)
In short, when ever the circuit is powered and the measured voltage is more then the expected normal voltage, the circuit is open.
The expected normal voltage for any sense resistor R (ohms) for any load A (Amps) can be found:
normal voltage = 12 - (12 * (R / (12/A))) 


Thanks for the detailed explaination . Got your point.

Thanks for the detailed explaination . Got your point.
I found this chip : https://www.mikroe.com/hall-current-7-click which have the desired resistor, embedded processor , ADC and I2C interface which I believe can be used.
Sorry, please can you clarify on this : "Measure the voltage between the resistor and bulb. If the same as the supply, then the wire is probably cut/bulb burned out. " . I am not able to comprehend that if the wire is cut, then voltage is same as the original.

Ok, at the near end you have 12 Volt power and a small resistor. Then all that cable you want to make sure is not cut. Then the incandescent light bulb you want to make sure is not blown out. Now, measure the voltage on the far side of the small resistor from the 12 Volt power source. If you picked it correctly, and the incandescent light bulb is lit, you should read about 10.9 Volts.  But if the cable to the light bulb is cut or the light bulb is burned out, you should then read 12 volts. The bulb requires current to light up. That current will cause a voltage drop across that small resistor.
